# Why is my Pygame Collision always colliding?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, pygame-surface

I have been trying to use Pygame collision, but nothing I have tried has works. Now I have ended up with this:

```py
player_collison_box = player.get_rect()   
hole_collision_box = hole.get_rect() 
if player_collison_box.colliderect(hole_collision_box):
    print('collision')
```

It doesn't throw out any errors or anything, but it just always prints 'collide'. I don't know if the collide boxes are too big or both at the same spot or something, but can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The Surface is placed at a position when it is `blit` to the display.

You've to set the location of the rectangle, by a keyword argument. In the following (*player_x*, *player_y*) are the coordinates of the player and (*hole_x*, *hole_y*) ar eth coordinates of the hole:

```py
player_collison_box = player.get_rect(topleft = (player_x, player_y))
hole_collision_box = hole.get_rect(topleft = (hole_x, hole_y))
if player_collison_box.colliderect(hole_collision_box):
    print('collision')
```